# Whats the advantage of having deleted/updated time/creation dates about a table record?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Whats the advantage of having deleted/updated time/creation dates about a table record?
I saw some system where tables have DELETED (boolean), CREATED_DATE (datetime), UPDATED (datetime) extra fields... what is its advantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done for audit purposes. You should do it only if you have a corresponding requirement in your design.

For stronger flavors of history keeping, consider [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), or [temporal tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database).

Comment: How does CQRS fit in with this? Typically auditing is trigger driven and happens on the Command (D/U/I DML) as part of the transaction

Comment: @gbn All CQRS implementations that I've seen or wrote keep a log of domain-level actions (although one may reasonably argue that a log is an implementation detail). By examining that log you can get the info on when a value has been inserted, deleted, updated, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's suitable for auditing. You can present when (and often who) altered/deleted a record.
Other uses include purging old records based on their age, presenting old relation data as the relation were when the record was active, and generally, tracking changes over time.

Answer (score 1):

The main raisons are:

- to audit changes on table at record level without history changes (only last change).
- Concurrency control in [disconnected database acces model](http://stargazer.bridgeport.edu/sed/projects/cs597/Fall_2001/dkiran/chapter3.html): App read record, before save it check if row has changed in middle time.

Answer (score 1):

With the deleted boolean, you just flag the entry as deleted, instead of actually deleting it from the database. That way you keep all data, even deleted, instead of just throwing it away. That way you can cancel/recover a deleted entry for instance.

Created date can be convenient in many cases, when a blog post was created, when a user signed up etc. Update would tell you when the data was last edited.

Answer (score 1):

In certain fields (Finance, Medical at least) then you are **obliged** to have full audit trails, by regulation or law. This will be regularly audited too

As well as separate tables (with extra temporal information) for historic, information about an entry is usually stored in the row too as you have noted. Typically "When" and "By" columns for Created, Changed, Deactivated etc.

The idea of the "IsDeleted" is called a logical or soft delete to preserve data.
Most systems I've worked on disallow "hard" deletes except under certain conditions